# Android Studio prints the error line incorrectly for Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, compiler-errors

I have a very interesting problem for me. I have 2 files. I created one of these files on Android Studio. I copied the other one from a different project. The contents of these files are exactly the same. When I run my Flutter project with the file I created in Android studio, the line number appears as 1 when the error occurs. But when I run it with the file I copied from a different project, it correctly logs the line of code that generates the error when an error occurs. What could be the problem?

Code available in both files:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class SplashBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Map<String, String> data = {};
    print("geldi");
    print(data['test']!);
  }
}
```

The log generated when I use the file I created in Android studio:
[image]

The log that occurs when I use the file that I changed the content of by copying it from a different project:
[image: The log that occurs when I use the file that I changed the content of by copying it from a different project.]

Properties of files
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I created a file in Android Studio running on Macos, the line separator was selected by default and it created the files in CR format. The problem was fixed when I changed the line separator format of the files to LF.

[image]

After doing this process, different line separators need to be fixed in each of your existing files. To do this faster, you can make the line separator fail for files that differ from the selected settings.

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html#change_line_ending